# How to increase vm.max_map_count?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to run Elastic search in an Ubuntu EC2 machine (t2.medium).

But I'm getting the message:

> max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]

How can I increase the `vm.max_map_count` value?

Comment: First hit on Google... https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/vm-max-map-count.html

Answer (score 148, accepted):

To make it persistent, you can add this line:

```
vm.max_map_count=262144
```

in your `/etc/sysctl.conf` and run

```
$ sudo sysctl -p
```

to reload configuration with new value

Comment: `cat /proc/sys/vm/max_map_count` is unaffected by this which is strage to me

Comment: Doesn't work for me, after reboot back to default (Ubuntu 18.04)

Answer (score 33):

I use

```
# sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

And for the persistence configuration

```
# echo "vm.max_map_count=262144" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Att.

Comment: In case did not work like above instead do it like  sudo /bin/su -c  "echo 'vm.max_map_count=262144' >> /etc/sysctl.conf"

Answer (score 21):

Note that

> From version 207 and 21x, systemd only applies settings from
> /etc/sysctl.d/*.conf and /usr/lib/sysctl.d/*.conf. If you had
> customized /etc/sysctl.conf, you need to rename it as
> /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf. If you had e.g. /etc/sysctl.d/foo, you
> need to rename it to /etc/sysctl.d/foo.conf.

See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/sysctl#Configuration

So add `vm.max_map_count=262144` in `/etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf` and then run

> sudo sysctl --system

Answer (score 13):

```
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

Answer (score 8):

When:

> permission denied on key 'vm.max_map_count'

```
sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

Comment: When I check the value afterwards, its still unchanged: `sysctl vm.max_map_count`

Comment: You missed 'sudo'?

Comment: No, but thanks for the answer. I am using a vserver which does not allow changing this value.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using ubuntu VM, then navigate to etc folder.

1. Run `vim sysctl.conf`
2. Add `vm.max_map_count=262144` to the end of the file and save
3. Finally run `sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144` this command 
   you will see `vm.max_map_count=262144`

Comment: Just wondering from a Linux intermediate user perspective; the `-w` flag means it writes the info, but in line 2 above you already manually wrote the info to the file. So why write it again on line 3?

Answer (score 2):

Following command as worked fine on Fedora 28 (Linux 4.19 Kernel)

`sudo echo "vm.max_map_count=262144" >> /etc/sysctl.d/elasticsearchSpecifications.conf && sudo sysctl --system`

Answer (score 0):

I found that when adding the settings to `/etc/sysctl.conf`, the system actually saved the changes to `/etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf`.

And when saving the changes to `/etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf`, it's also saved to `/etc/sysctl.conf`, so I think they both point to the same file.

Comment: /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf is a link to /etc/sysctl.conf