# Kibana unabe to connect to elasticsearch on windows

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, startup, timeoutexception

I am running elastic search 7.6 it is working ok on http://localhost:9200/ . I am able to use the REST API to add values to index.

Now when i start up kibana 7.6, i get following error:-

```
log   [12:31:32.247] [info][plugins-service] Plugin "case" is disabled.
  log   [12:31:44.432] [info][plugins-system] Setting up [36] plugins: [taskManager,siem,licensing,infra,encryptedSavedObjects,code,timelion,features,security,usageCollection,metrics,canvas,apm_oss,translations,reporting,status_page,share,uiActions,data,navigation,newsfeed,kibana_legacy,management,dev_tools,home,spaces,cloud,graph,inspector,expressions,visualizations,embeddable,advancedUiActions,dashboard_embeddable_container,eui_utils,bfetch]                                   log   [12:31:44.435] [info]
  log   [12:31:44.587] [info][savedobjects-service] Waiting until all Elasticsearch nodes are compatible with Kibana before starting saved objects migrations...
  log   [12:31:44.617] [info][savedobjects-service] Starting saved objects migrations                                     log   [12:31:44.657] [info][savedobjects-service] Creating index .kibana_1.
  log   [12:31:44.663] [info][savedobjects-service] Creating index .kibana_task_manager_1. 
  log   [12:32:14.663] [warning][savedobjects-service] Unable to connect to Elasticsearch. Error: Request Timeout after 30000ms
```

> Unable to connect to Elasticsearch. Error: Request Timeout after
>   30000ms

Comment: Are you starting a fresh kibana 7.6 or upgrading kibana ?

Comment: Fresh Kibana 7.6

Comment: there was a issue with APM plugin ...i removed that plugin now stuck on this error

Comment: now I reinstalled Kibana , etting the following issue:-

Comment: log   [06:34:59.768] [warning][savedobjects-service] Unable to connect to Elasticsearch. Error: [resource_already_exists_exception] index [.kibana_1/KE1kiXYMR2qjbG9qhK2ynw] already exists, with { index_uuid="KE1kiXYMR2qjbG9qhK2ynw" & index=".kibana_1" }
  log   [06:34:59.769] [warning][savedobjects-service] Another Kibana instance appears to be migrating the index. Waiting for that migration to complete. If no other Kibana instance is attempting migrations, you can get past this message by deleting index .kibana_1 and restarting Kibana.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got same problem like yours, and I've sloved it by switching `cmd prompt` window to `PowerShell` window. It seems that `command prompt` window is very sensitive. You may get some idea here. https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-7-4-0-on-windows-command-prompt-not-able-to-start/203877/7

BTW, If you get a warning when you restart Kibana, like:

```
  log   [06:27:47.136] [warning][savedobjects-service] Unable to connect to Elasticsearch. Error: [resource_already_exists_exception] index [.kibana_task_manager_1/EmPx77s1TLWbLQdqQ8iC0w] already exists, with { index_uuid="EmPx77s1TLWbLQdqQ8iC0w" & index=".kibana_task_manager_1" }
  log   [06:27:47.140] [warning][savedobjects-service] Another Kibana instance appears to be migrating the index. Waiting for that migration to complete. If no other Kibana instance is attempting migrations, you can get past this message by deleting index .kibana_task_manager_1 and restarting Kibana.
```

Just do what it told you, delete the index `.kibana_task_manager_1` and restart Kibana.

> curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/.kibana_task_manager_1

Good Luck.