# Kibana all index gone after update

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-7

My cluster consisting of 2 node.
I Just finished updated my elk stack. Previously 7.8, now 7.12. I used to have problem where kibana cannot be started and it shown **Kibana server is not ready yet**. After some research it finally solved by doing

`curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/.kibana*`

The real problem is, all my indexes are gone. I check on discovers and even kibana>index patterns, I don't think it is deleted because when I check on stack monitoring, the disk still the same, but on elasticsearch shard it written missing replica shards. But on
Stack Management > Transforms, there are still some running progress or my previous transforms and all the indexes still completely shown on Stack Management > Index management.

What happened? How I access them again?

Comment: Index patterns are stored inside the `.kibana` index. Why did you delete it?

Comment: Hi Val, I was following some instruction, we have the same problem and it solved his problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58011088/kibana-server-is-not-ready-yet